# Перенос скриптов SQL в mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Создавал большую БД в SQL Server на локальном ПК, когда планировался сервер с Windows. Планы изменились и было решено использовать удаленный Linux сервер. Создал в SQL сценарий через "Мастер формирования сценариев". Воспользовался ресурсом [sql-hub](http://sql-hub.com/Page/index.php?Shortname=amstomy), что бы конвертировать получившийся скрипт из SQL в MySQL, но Workbench все равно выдает кучу ошибок. Вопрос - есть ли сервис который умеет конвертировать без ошибок, возможно ли это вообще и можно ли вместе с скриптами создания таблиц, создать в SQL Server сценарий для их заполнения? Так же интересует вопрос - есть ли в Mysql аналог для `uniqueidentifier`?

Comment: Для `uniqueidentifier` можно использовать `CHAR(38)`. Для генерации `GUID` используйте функцию `UUID()`.

Comment: Сервис? да порой и руками-то не вдруг придумаешь, как сделать...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> и можно ли вместе с скриптами создания таблиц, создать в SQL Server сценарий для их заполнения ?

Можно. На шаге сохранения скриптов, нажмите кнопку Дополнительно [image: Дополнительно] , и установите свойство "Типы данных для внесения в срипт" в значение "схема и данные".

Comment: кнопки _Дополнительно_ нет. Вот как я делаю : правой кнопкой по базе -> задачи -> сформировать сценарий -> далее -> (выбираю нужную базу данных) -> далее -> (выбор параметров сценария не меняю) -> далее -> (выбор типов обьектов - таблицы) -> далее -> (все таблицы) -> далее -> вывести сценарий в файл -> готово.

Comment: Картинку прикрепил к ответу.

Comment: какая у вас версия manager studio ?

Comment: у меня нет кнопки дополнительно

Comment: Если не ошибаюсь, такая возможность есть во всех версияx, начиная с 2005. Картинка сделана в MS2014 Express edition.

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался